# Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib' in TF2.1.0

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

```py
if quantize_layer:
    if is_training:
        tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph()
    else:
        tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph()
```

ERROR:

> File "retrain/tflearn.py", line 771, in add_final_retrain_ops
>       tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph() AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

When I am running this code, I am getting the above error. if tf.contrib was removed from tf2, then what is the alternative for tf.contrib in TF2.1.0?
 Can anyone help me in sorting out this error by telling any alternative for the tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph in Tensorflow2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

As you might have guessed `contrib` module was removed in TF2 if you navigate to its documentation page https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib it shows warning:

> Warning: The tf.contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0. Many of its submodules have been integrated into TensorFlow core, or spun-off into other projects like tensorflow_io, or tensorflow_addons. For instructions on how to upgrade see the Migration guide.

Looks like `quantize` you use was migrated into https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization, eg:

```py
tf.quantization.quantize(
    input,
    min_range,
    max_range,
    T,
    mode='MIN_COMBINED',
    round_mode='HALF_AWAY_FROM_ZERO',
    name=None,
    narrow_range=False,
    axis=None,
    ensure_minimum_range=0.01
)
```

Comment: Bunch of things changed in TF2 it would be better I think if you post another question which will be specific to replacing `create_training_graph` in TF2 where you would include more logic around why you are using it. Also there is an upgrade script which might help https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade